# Passing a control name as string to the Form Object in VBA

Tags: vba, forms, object

I'm passing control names as strings into a sub because the code can apply to many forms and controls and subform controls. I can't figure out how to address the control when passed as a string using: With f Form Object.

```
  This works fine:
  Dim sControlName as string
  sControlName = "myControlName"
  Forms!myFormName.myChildFormName.Form(sControlName).Top = {some value}

  This will also work:
  Dim f as Form
  Set f = Forms!myFormName
  With f
      .myChildFormName.Form(sControlName).Top = {some value}
 End With

  This does not work:
  Dim f as Form
  Set f = Forms!myFormName.myChildFormName.Form
  With f
      'How do I get this below to work?
      (sControlName).Top = {some value}
  End With
```

Answer (score 0):

After more trial and error the proper way to construct this is:

```
 Dim sControlName as string
 Dim f as Form
 sControlName = "myControlName"
 Set f = Forms!myFormName.myChildFormName.Form   {or any form }

 f(sControlName).Top = { some value }

 i.e. don't use With f / End With
```